# Wait until element exists, loop, then store in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

```
var i =1;
function waitForElClass(data){
  var element = data.selected;
  var index = data.index;

  var findEl = document.getElementsByClassName(element)[index];
  console.log(i);
  i++;
  window.setTimeout(function(){
    if(!$(findEl).length){
      waitForElClass(data);
    }else{
      console.log(findEl);
      return findEl;
    }
  },500)
}
```

I'm trying to get an element (sometimes with and ID, class, or one of a group of class elements. This example is of the latter) that is being loaded onto a page with JS, meaning I need to wait for it by asking it every few milliseconds.

I'm trying to then store it in a variable, with

```
var data = {selected: 'new', index: 0};
var elem = waitForElClass(data);
```

and it's finding the element, printing it, but not storing it in `elem`. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Try removing `var` from the declaration of `elem`. This way it should be a global instance

Comment: Your `return` statement inside your `setTimeOut` is returning from that inside anonymous function. Your outer function completes before the first run as it likely doesn't take `500ms` and returns null. Look into promises for this type of behavior.

Comment: This element is created dynamically???

Comment: What is expected result if element exists ? To log the element at `console` ? What is purpose of including `return findEl;` at `waitForElClass` function ?

Comment: this use-case screams out for [mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) instead of DOM polling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are performing an asyncrhonous task, I'd suggest modifying your code to accept a callback, or return a promise. Here is a callback modification:

```
var i =1;
function waitForElClass(data, cb){
  var element = data.selected;
  var index = data.index;

  var findEl = document.getElementsByClassName(element)[index];
  console.log(i);
  i++;
  var to = window.setInterval(function(){
    if($(findEl).length){
      console.log(findEl);
      cb(findEl);
      window.clearInterval(to);
    }
  },500)
}
```

It could then be used as follows:

```
var data = {selected: 'new', index: 0};
var element;
waitForElClass(data, function(el) {
  element = el;
  //or something more meaningful here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How are these elements coming up into the DOM tree? Via traditional page load? If so you can use the `DOMContentLoaded` event to know the right moment to get the elements you want.

Here is a very simple example on how to do it:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('youElementClassHere'));
});
```

Another simple option is to simple reference your elements in a script at the bottom of your `<body>` tag.

Comment: OP indicated the elements are being loaded via JS, so I don't think this one would work.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that we have `async` execution, you should better introduce the usage of `callbacks` as follows:

```
var i = 1;

function waitForElClass(data, callback) {
  var element = data.selected;
  var index = data.index;

  var findEl = document.getElementsByClassName(element)[index];
  console.log(i);
  i++;
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    if (!$(findEl).length) {
      waitForElClass(data);
    } 
    else {
      callback(findEl); // executing callback
    }
  }, 500)
}

var data = {selected: 'new', index: 0};
var elem;
waitForElClass(data, function(el) { // Callback
   console.log(el);
});
```